# tsc compile import with wrong path, adding index at the end of @angular/material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am trying to buiding a library to agregate and distribute a set of angular components between multiple projects, with a dependancy on [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2). My goal is to publish it in npm.

Having an issue when running `tsc` to package the lib, `.js` file try to import `from '@angular/material/index'`.  Same file `.d.ts` import `from '@angular/material'` and I do not understand where this difference is coming from.

My gulp  :

```
import {main as tsc} from '@angular/tsc-wrapped';

const libraryRoot = join('/../myproject/src', 'lib');
const tsconfigPath = join(libraryRoot, 'tsconfig.json');

task('library:build:esm', () => tsc(tsconfigPath, {basePath: libraryRoot}));
```

My tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "stripInternal": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../../dist/packages/mila-angular",
    "paths": {},
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "types": [
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "public-api.ts",
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "flatModuleOutFile": "index.js",
    "flatModuleId": "mila-angular",
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true
  }
}
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
```

**myComponent.d.ts**

```
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
```

**myComponent.js**

```
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material/index';
```

As a result, when importing my library I have the following error message :

```
import { ButtonModule } from 'myLibrary';

ERROR in ./~/myLibrary/myLibrary.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/index' in '/.../myProject/node_modules/myLibrary'
 @ ./~/myLibrary/myLibrary.es5.js 8:0-80
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

If i manually edit `myLibrary.es5.js` and remove `/index` everything works fine.

*(All process is highly inspried by @angular/material buildind process)*

Comment: If I remove "annotateForClosureCompiler": true, then import in .js no longer have index, but ... import no longer work :). I'll have to investigate around this.

Comment: Anyone know the cause of this? I have an internal library that works with angular cli apps directly but when referenced from an other library '/index' is added to the end. Only .js and .d.ts file are published and installed. Deleting node_modules and npm i didn't solve.

Comment: Sounds like a different issue ... I would recommend to create a new question referring to this one for more visibility, with more details ;)

Comment: @WilliamLohan Please share a link if you do so, maybe I could help ;)

Comment: I found these issues:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16084
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16152
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17171
https://github.com/angular/tsickle/issues/376
I don't use ClosureCompiler and setting `"annotateForClosureCompiler": false` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, found my problem but for un unknown reason npm did install `@angular/material` with full code instead of builded version. I was having all `.ts` files and `index.ts` so I guess tsc did natuarlly used it.

Solved it we deleting `node_modules` folder and running `npm i` again.